# When running a python script with -m, why isn't __init__.py called?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a directory structure like this:

```
root/
    __init__.py
    moduleA/
        __init__.py  # prints "hello"
        myscript.py
```

If I run `python -m moduleA.myscript` from the `root` directory, `hello` will be printed out. However, if I run `python -m myscript` from the `moduleA` directory, it won't.

Why doesn't the `__init__.py` which is in the current directory when executing `python -m` get called?

Comment: being in module you are calling script that's y only script get called not __init__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question i understand that `__init__.py` inside `moduleA` has the print hello code.

**So when you execute from the root directory the `__init__.py` file will work. But when you come inside the directory. That file won't work.**

By using the `python -m module` option it's work same as the `python module.py` nothing else.

Read about [`__init__.py`](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-is-init-py-used-for.htm)

Comment: So there is literally no way to run package-related files when using `python -m` and specifying a script in the current directory?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend running the **python -m  myScript.py** file from the **root/** directory. If you have further questions I'd recommend reading up on the

> Django framework documentation

You can find it on [The official Django documentation page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0)

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really answer my question, I'm trying to understand this behaviour change when running from different points in the hierarchy.

Comment: This is because **__init__.py** shouldn't be in the root/ directory because when you call python -m from a different directory it will exclude the __init__.py file located in your root folder it disregards that code lest you specify where you want your code to be run from e.g. python -m /root/__init__.py